# ¿Cómo intercambiar colores saltando uno desde una consulta - PHP/MYSQLI?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un diseño de tablas HTML, donde la primera columna horizontal siempre es gris y la segunda es blanca, luego se repetí el mismo proceso, gris y luego blanca y así sucesivamente la cual representa de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- La clase `b-color` representa el color gris `<tr class="b-color"></tr>`
- La clase `bg-color` representa el color blanco `<tr class="bg-color"></tr>`

De la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_best_teams,rank,country,total_points,previous_points FROM best_teams WHERE active=? order by id_best_teams ASC LIMIT 3");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);
$active = "1";

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($id_best_teams, $rank, $country, $total_points, $previous_points);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr class="b-color">
            <td class="rank">'.$rank.'.</td>
            <td class="country">'.$country.'</td>
            <td class="t-points">'.$total_points.'</td>
            <td class="t-points p-points">'.$previous_points.'</td>
          </tr>';
    }
  } else {
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

¿Como puedo hacer que el mismo diseño de tabla HTML se conserve es decir los colores?

Como imprimir los resultados de la siguiente manera ya especificada arriba, la primera columna horizontal que siempre sea gris y la segunda sea blanca, luego que se repita el mismo proceso, gris y luego blanca y así sucesivamente como lo mostraba la imagen.

Comment: Ya existe css para esto, ¿Por que no lo haces de esa manera?, aquí ejemplos https://galussothemes.com/css3/alternar-el-color-de-las-filas-de-una-tabla-con-css3

Comment: @ChristopherVilla Gracias por lo comentado a lo mejor puedes escribirlo como una respuesta alterna, siempre es bueno tener más referencias no solamente para mí, si no para otros usuarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un contador y agregar la clase adecuada dependiendo del valor del mismo.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_best_teams,rank,country,total_points,previous_points FROM best_teams WHERE active=? order by id_best_teams ASC LIMIT 3");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);
$active = "1";

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($id_best_teams, $rank, $country, $total_points, $previous_points);
  $i = 0;
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr class="' . ($i % 2 == 0 ? 'b-color' : 'bg-color') . '">
            <td class="rank">'.$rank.'.</td>
            <td class="country">'.$country.'</td>
            <td class="t-points">'.$total_points.'</td>
            <td class="t-points p-points">'.$previous_points.'</td>
          </tr>';
    $i++;
    }
  } else {
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: Si, a mi si me funciono.

Comment: Gracias amigo :)